# Scalar Products equation proof

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, proof-writing, inner-products

$\langle \langle x + y, z \rangle \rangle = \langle \langle x, z \rangle \rangle + \langle  \langle y, z \rangle \rangle$

It is clear when there are only $\langle \dot \ , \dot \ \rangle$ but what about the $\langle \langle \dot \ , \dot \ \rangle \rangle$

Please use the above mentioned notation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that $\langle\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\rangle$ is used simply as a general scalar product, to distinguish from a particular scalar product (such as the dot product) that has been previously denoted by $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle.$